# Return a word in a visual-studio-code extension

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, vscode-extensions

I am making an extension in visual-studio-code, in typescript.
And I need to return a word (in combination with dots and hyphens) after the **'{{>'** prefix.

```
{{>word-test }}
{{> word-test}}
{{> word-test }}
{{> word-test class="class_name"}}
// returns 'word-test'

// On this one the regex doesn't seem to work
{{> word-test 
    class="class_name"
}}
// returns all the text in the file

{{> word-test.test }}
// returns 'word-test.test'
```

To get the words I use the **'getWordRangeAtPosition'** built in in visual-studio-code with a regex in the parameter.

#### The problem

I have tried a few regex combinations, but when there is a line-break I never get the 'word-test' returned in visual-studio-code.
Instead i get all the text in the file.

Here is the most recent regex combination I have tried:

```
/(?<={{>[ \s]{0,1})(.*?)(?=[\n\s\}\}])/
```

It works all fine in a regex tester, but not in visual-studio-code itself.

see the regex tester: https://regexr.com/4o4d8

Comment: Some comments: 1) space is already included in `\s` and `{0,1}` is `?`, then `[ \s]{0,1}` <=> `\s?` 2) twice the same character in  character class doesn't make sense, `(?=[\n\s\}\}])` <=> `[\s}]+` 3) lookbehind is not supported in many browsers (for example Firefox)

Comment: Do you mean like `(?<={{>\s*)\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*(?=[\s\S]*?}})` https://regex101.com/r/AxRVG9/1

Comment: The [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument) says: "A custom regular expression will **fail to match multiline strings** and in the name of speed regular expressions should not match words with spaces. Use TextLine.text for more complex, non-wordy, scenarios." So what you get is the intended behavior. You need to use TextLine.text.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a complicated RegEx, can you write the logic in your extension code?

You can find the word on position, then get the leading text from the same line in the document, and test that the leading text ends with `{{>`:

```js
let wordRange = document.getWordRangeAtPosition(position, /\w[-\w\.]*/g);
let leadingText = document.getText(new Range(wordRange.start.with({ character: 0 }), wordRange.start));
let hasCorrectPrefix = leadingText.match(/{{>\s?$/);
```

Similarly you could compare the suffix, if it is really necessary for the functionality.